# Combine Words and Generate Variations From Multiple Textbox

Tags: c#, for-loop, textbox

[image]

Above is the screenshot what I am try to achieve when user press generate i want to generate all possible combination in that order of keyword 1 + keyword 2 + keyword 3.

example in this case if user generate results should be

top knee brace
top leg brace
best knee brace
best leg brace
cat knee brace
cat leg brace

depending on the text entered i trying to generate all possible combinations but stuck since I am not able to figure logic.

this what I have done so far

1. I created 3 different lists and add textbox lines to their appropriate list (list 1 contains - top,best,cat), (list 2 contains - knee, leg) and (list 3 contains - brace)
2. created class which accepts three list parameters and try generate all possible combination using for loop and finally removing all duplicates but for loop logic is not working.

code-

```
public List<string> CombineKeywords(List<string> keyword1, List<string> keyword2, List<string> keyword3)
    {
        List<string> combinedKeywords = new List<string>();

        for (int entryKeyword1 = 0; entryKeyword1 < keyword1.Count; entryKeyword1++)
        {
            combinedKeywords.Add(String.Concat(keyword1[entryKeyword1], " ", keyword2[entryKeyword1], " ", keyword3[entryKeyword1]));

            for (int entryKeyword2 = 0; entryKeyword2 < keyword2.Count; entryKeyword2++)
            {
                combinedKeywords.Add(String.Concat(keyword1[entryKeyword1], " ", keyword2[entryKeyword2], " ", keyword3[entryKeyword1]));

                for (int entryKeyword3 = 0; entryKeyword3 < keyword3.Count; entryKeyword3++)
                {
                    combinedKeywords.Add(String.Concat(keyword1[entryKeyword1], " ", keyword2[entryKeyword1], " ", keyword3[entryKeyword3]));
                }
            }
        }

        List<string> uniquecombinedKeywords = combinedKeywords.Distinct().ToList();
        return uniquecombinedKeywords;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a set of trying-every-combination nested loops can become somehow difficult when dealing with undetermined amounts (e.g., any number of elements between 10 and 100).

In situations like the one you are proposing (3 variables with 3 loops), you just need to be systematic with the indices and remember that the combinations are created in the most internal loop.

A corrected version of your code:

```
for (int entryKeyword1 = 0; entryKeyword1 < keyword1.Count; entryKeyword1++)
{
    for (int entryKeyword2 = 0; entryKeyword2 < keyword2.Count; entryKeyword2++)
    {
        for (int entryKeyword3 = 0; entryKeyword3 < keyword3.Count; entryKeyword3++)
        {
            combinedKeywords.Add(String.Concat(keyword1[entryKeyword1], " ", keyword2[entryKeyword2], " ", keyword3[entryKeyword3]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome your a life safer now I understand what I did wrong